# Get current language set on Android device

Tags: android

I have a edittext which the user enters some text into

Once they press the submit button I process the text they entered.

I need to apply different logic if they have entered English and any other language.

What's the best way to assess if its English they have entered?

1) Get the language of the keyboard? Is this possible. On my SE XPeria I can change the keyboard language and the device local still remains English

2) Analyse the string to check if its in English???

3) Worst case scenario I ask the user if they entered English

Comment: Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() and getLanguage and getISO3Language all return English even though my keyboard is set to Hebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using the Unicode of the characters entered.
Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, that would be slower for the record, would be to use an online service such as Google translate or http://detectlanguage.com/ APIs. You could send a portion of the string off and then process the response to see what language was entered.